# Automatically refactor multiple variable definition to single declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-refactoring

Are there any tools or methods that can automatically replace multiple variable definitions with "one declaration per variable"?

For example, given

```
var one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3;
```

I would like to automatically refactor this to:

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = 3;
```

This is the same as enforcing the [ESLint one-var rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/one-var), but with an automatic refactor of existing 'wrong' implementations. The ESLint rule is not included in the list of available 'auto-fixes'.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a [Program Transformation System (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).  These are tools that parse source code to internal forms (usually Abstract Syntax Trees), and allow you to apply *source-to-source code transformations* to modify those forms (trees).  After all changes have been made, they can regenerate source code from the modified AST.

Some PTS are wired to operate only on one particular language (often a single dialect).  The more general ones accept a description of the programming language to be used as a parameter, and can thus be used for tasks in many languages.

Transformations are usually written in the form,

```
  if you see *this*, replace it by *that* when *condition*
```

where *this* and *that* are patterns expressed in the source language of interest, and *condition* is an extra predicate controlling whether the specific transformation should apply. [Consider "if you see x/x, replace it by 1 when x not equal 0" as a motivating example for the conditional].  This usually means you can write these transformations without knowing the precise detail of the ASTs...  and you can read these transforms *after* you have written them.

As an example, our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [JavaScript front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/ECMAScriptFrontEnd.html) can do OP's operation.  The JavaScript front end contains a precise grammar for JavaScript, assuring the source code is parsed properly to an AST; it also contains an AST to text prettyprinter used to regenerate text as a final result.

We assume the grammar rule for statements for ECMASCript has been marked as *associative*:

```
[associative] StatementList = StatementList Statement;
```

This means that you can insert a statement in the middle of such a list without changing its (associative) list-like property.

Here are (untested but very close to right) rules for DMS to do the job:

```
domain ECMAScript~MicrosoftNetscape; -- establish language/dialect of interest

rule break_up_complex_var1(vdl: VariableDeclarationList, i: Identifier): StatementList -> StatementList =
   "var \vdl, \i;" ->  "var \vdl; var \i;"

rule break_up_complex_var2(vdl: VariableDeclarationList, i: Identifier, e: Expression): StatementList -> StatementList =
   "var \vdl, \i=\e;" ->  "var \vdl; var \i=\e;"

ruleset break_up_complex_var =
   { break_up_complex_var1,
     break_up_complex_var2 };
```

DMS rewrite rules have names (e.g., **break_up_complex_var1** and **...var2**), and operate over *patterns* written in *metaquotes*  " .... ", which are used to distinguish targeted-language (e.g., ECMAScript) syntax from the syntax of the DMS rewrite rules.  Within the meta quotes, a back-slashed item is a *pattern match variable*, which represents a language sub-phrase as describe in the rule header, e.g, "\i" refers to an identifier. Each rule has a pattern (*this*) and replacement (*that*) each written in metaquotes.  The funny **->** operator means *is replaced by*. Pattern match variables are bound by a left hand side match; the bound value is implicitly substituted in the right pattern if the pattern variable is mentioned there.  These particular rules don't require conditions.  More details on the [DMS Rewrite Rule formalism can be found here](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html).

We provide two rules: one to handle the case of a variable declaration which is not initialized, and one to handle the case where the declaration is made with initialization.  In both cases, we specify that we want to pick up what amounts to the last declaration in a **var** statement, and make a separate **var** statement for that last declaration.  The *ruleset* tells DMS to treat these two rules as a set; it is easy to get DMS to apply this ruleset everywhere (not shown in this answer).  After the rules are applied, DMS prettyprints the modified ASTs.  Voila.

This is a rather simple application of DMS, but it would be entirely reliable. The patterns are precise; they cannot match anything other than what they describe.  The replacements are required by DMS to be syntactically well formed; this doesn't guarantee correctness but is a necessary condition for correctness, that also catches lots of stupid errors in defining rules.  In this case the rules are semantically correct, and that should be obvious by inspection (e.g., you can read the rules after somebody else wrote them).

Given that initializer expressions ("context free") can be arbitrarily complex and contain nested () {} and [], you **cannot** implement this with text hacking or even text hacking with regexes.   A PTS is the right way to do this.

Normally we do more complex things with DMS but this is a nice simple example. (I'm not sure this task motivates actually using DMS to achieve OPs' specific effect).  More interesting tasks involve using dozens of transformations (and often some additional analyses of the code, not discussed here) all sequenced to achieve complex massive refactoring tasks.  It should be clear that these more complex tasks can't be done by string hacking with regexes, either.

Comment: I love the downvoters.  This answers OP's question directly.